# Duplicate values inserted into database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I can add/remove input fields dynamically but I have a problem on inserting the  input values into my database, as there are duplicate values.

JQuery for input fields

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var counter = 1;
var max_fields = 10;
$('.my-form .add-box').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (counter < max_fields){
        counter++;
        $('#container').append(
            '<div><strong>Link #' + counter + '</strong><br />' 
            + '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" placeholder = "From" /><a href = "#" class = "remove-box"><img src = "Remove Button.png" height = "35" width = "35" align = "middle"/></a><br />' 
            + '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="fields[]' + '" type="text" placeholder = "To" /><a href = "#" class = "remove-box"><img src = "Remove Button.png" height = "35" width = "35" align = "middle"/></div></a>');
}
});
//code to remove fields
```

Data insertion

```
foreach ( $_POST['fields'] as $key=>$value ) {

        //Insert into transport table
        $sql_transport1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_transport (Origin,Destination) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
           mysql_real_escape_string($value),
           mysql_real_escape_string($value));

        $result_transport1 = $db->query($sql_transport1);
        $inserted_transport_id1 = $db->last_insert_id();
}
```

Value entered:

- Origin#1-> here, Destination#1: there
- Origin#2-> house, Destination#2: airport

Output:
[image]

My take is that it has to do with this function `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but isn't it necessary to prevent SQL injection? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Also can't stress it enough, please stop using the mysql functions, either use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries and not `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: I intend to do so since it is deprecated, but I have to use mySQL as per my assignment's requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input form seems very strange to me.

If your forms asks for 2 origins and destinations your POST input will be:

```
"fields" => array("origin1", "destination1", "origin2", "destination2");
```

This can certainly work but not with the way your loop works currently. In this example using `$key,$value` you would input `0,origin1` `1,destination1` `2,origin2` `3,destination2`. That's not what you want at all, you want: `origin1,destination` and `origin2,destination2`.

There is a better solution.

Rather than naming the fields `fields` give them actual names:

```
+ '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="origins[]' + '" type="text" placeholder = "From" /><a href = "#" class = "remove-box"><img src = "Remove Button.png" height = "35" width = "35" align = "middle"/></a><br />' 
+ '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="destinations[]' + '" type="text" placeholder = "To" /><a href = "#" class = "remove-box"><img src = "Remove Button.png" height = "35" width = "35" align = "middle"/></div></a>');
```

Now in PHP you can do:

```
foreach ($_POST["origins"] as $index => $origin) {
    $destination = $_POST["destinations"][$index];

    $sql_transport1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_transport (Origin,Destination) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
       mysql_real_escape_string($origin),
       mysql_real_escape_string($destination));
    // run query etc.
}
```

You will need to add some checks to see if all the indexes exist etc etc.

Comment: Thank you for the input buddy. Learn something new again today haha.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're using `$value` twice

```
$sql_transport1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_transport (Origin,Destination) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
           mysql_real_escape_string($value),
           mysql_real_escape_string($value));
```

Try using `$key` for one of the values

```
$sql_transport1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO tbl_transport (Origin,Destination) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
           mysql_real_escape_string($key),
           mysql_real_escape_string($value));
```

Comment: I tried that before, this is the output.Origin#1-> 0, Destination#1: here

Origin#2-> 1, Destination#2: there

Comment: `$key` will be `0` `1` `2` etc. OP doesn't want these indexes for anything.